# Fluent NHibernate - bind List<int>

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a Class which looks something like this:

```
 public class User {
      public virtual int ID;
      public virtual string Name;
      public virtual IList<int> userRights;
 }

 I want to make a UserMap : ClassMap<User>
```

Mapping the name is no problem however i cant seem to figure out how to map the userRights.

Table looks like

```
UserTable
User_id int
User_Name nvarchar
User_group int

UserRights
User_group int
RightID int
```

How would you map this ?

Comment: Actually, the first time I answered I realized I didn't read it closely enough. Conceptually you also have something called a User_group.  In NHibernate the many-to-* typically work on the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want a List you need an index. So I would recommend just making it an ICollection unless the ordering is significant.

The mapping should look something like:

```
HasMany(x=> x.userRights).Element("RightID").AsBag();
```

However, upon looking at your tables, I noticed something odd. You're trying to use a one-to-many without having the primary key in the User_Rights table. If you had User_Id in UserRights the above should work.

Otherwise it looks like there's a UserGroup, which should be modeled by your classes.