# How do I store a Serializable List<int> in FluentNhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

If I have the following (cut down for brevity)

```
public class TempCartMap : ClassMap<TempCart>
{
   Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
   Map(x => x.Products); // < This one
}

[Serializable]
public class TempCart {

  public TempCart(){
    Products = new List<int>();
  }

  public virtual IList<int> Products { get; set; }

}
```

I've looked at (http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/06/using-nhibernate-with-servicestack/) and (http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/03/ormlite-blobbing-done-with-nhibernate-and-serialized-json/) but is there a shorter, simpler, faster way of getting NHibernate to Serialize & De-serialize a column as above. 
Seems overkill to create a new IUserType class etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also store the Products-list as a separate table:

```
public class TempCartMap : ClassMap<TempCart>
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

    HasMany(x => x.Products)
        .Element("product_number")
        .KeyColumn("temp_cart_id")
        .Table("temp_cart_products")
    ;
}
```

Just to clarify the question: is there a reason why this is not wanted?

Comment: Just coded exactly that, based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877924/fluent-nhibernate-bind-listint (I put a correction in on that post as it says AsElement not Element) The serialization bits still of interest tbh but your right in that it "should" map fine to another table but currently that throws "No persister for: System.Int32"

Comment: The main issue I was having was with regards to a Persisence Specification test (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397669/nhibernate-mappingexception-no-persister-for-system-int32) Turns out that doesn't work with this kind of binding. Dumb time wasting mistake of the day :) wrote a different test and left that column out of the persistent spec test.