# NHibernate.MappingException : No persister for: System.Int32

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the following...

```
public class TempCartMap : ClassMap<TempCart>
{
   Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
   ...
   HasMany(x => x.Products)
    .Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
        .Table("tblCartProducts")
            .Element("ProductId").KeyColumn("CartId").AsBag();
}

[Serializable]
public class TempCart {

  public TempCart(){
    Products = new List<int>();
  }

  public virtual IList<int> Products { get; set; }

}
```

And a persistance specification:

```
    [Test]
    public void CanMapSaleCart()
    {
        SystemTime.Freeze();

        IList<int> list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};

        new PersistenceSpecification<SaleCart>(Session)
                        //Other PropertyChecks that work fine without the Next check
                        .CheckList(x => x.AdditionalProducts, list)
                        .VerifyTheMappings();
            }
```

If I change the *CheckList* to *CheckProperty* I get

> System.ApplicationException : For property 'Products' expected
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
>   but got '' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[System.Int32,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'

If I leave it *CheckList* I get

> NHibernate.MappingException : No persister for: System.Int32

Driving me nuts!

---

--- Additional

If I remove .Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
and create a new test (not using persistence specification)

```
[Test]
public void CanMapSaleCartWithAdditionalProducts()
{
    SaleCart sCart = FactoryGirl.Build<SaleCart>();
    sCart.AdditionalProducts = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

    Session.Save(sCart);
    FlushAndClear();
}
```

That saves as I'd expect it to, creating the sale cart then adding the products to the other table.

**TLDR**:
This issue appears to be because I'm trying to use a persistence specification test on int, while the persistence specification test in fact only accepts Entitys by name (str).
If anyone wants to expand on that, feel free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears to be because I'm trying to use a persistence specification test on int, while the persistence specification test in fact only accepts Entitys by name (str). If anyone wants to expand on that, feel free.